# Sublime text problem with quote coloring

Tags: editors, sublime-text

I'm using sublime text 3 with `latexing` plugin on ubuntu, and i have a weird error on every color scheme i use, specially with double quote.

[image]

Only the solarized theme seems to work, other theme have the same weird bug on coloring.

I'm using this configuration :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,french=guillemets,maxlevel=3]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[protrusion=true]{microtype}
```

Comment: This is not an error, it is intended: the coloring is the one for "invalid" pieces of code. In your case you are using `"` instead of the typographically correct `''` and `\`\`` for open and closed quotes.

Comment: I try with '' and i have the same color :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotation marks in LaTeX are *not* simply entered by typing `"`.
Depending on the language you may need different symbols for opening/closing quotes.
In English for example it is common to use ``` ``my quotation'' ```.
This is why the highlighting is marking your quotes as invalid code: the character `"` should not be used that way in correct LaTeX.

For internationalised quotes you may be interested in the csquotes and babel package.

Comment: I'm writing in french, so i use already csquote (see my update). Ok for correct latex in english, but correct latex in french is same ? i need to use this notation ``my quotation'' ?

Comment: The most flexible solution would be using `\enquote{my quotation}` which is a command of `csquotes`.
See the [documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf).
A less flexible solution is using unicode characters `«my quote»`.
The point here is that in any case you should not use `"`.

Comment: Ok :/ There is no way to force csquote to automatically replace `''text"" ` by the correct french quote at compilation ?

Comment: I try with this, without success, i have an error at compilation ...  \MakeAutoQuote{``}{''}

Comment: You should post a new question with this problem than.
The original question has been answered I think (if you think so you should mark this as an answer)